# Understanding Specific Python List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, list-comprehension

I am trying to use this code that produces all possible outcomes of a dice roll, given the number of dice and number of sides. This codes works (but I do not quite understand how the list comprehension is working.

```
def dice_rolls(dice, sides):
   """
   Equivalent to list(itertools.product(range(1,7), repeat=n)) except
   for returning a list of lists instead of a list of tuples.
   """
   result = [[]]
   print([range(1, sides + 1)] * dice)
   for pool in [range(1, sides + 1)] * dice:
      result = [x + [y] for x in result for y in pool]
   return result
```

Therefore, I am trying to re-write the list comprehension

```
result = [x + [y] for x in result for y in pool]
```

into FOR loops to try to make sense of how it is working, but am currently unable to properly do it. Current failed code:

```
for x in result:
   for y in pool:
      result = [x + [y]]
```

2nd Question: If I wanted to make this into a generator (because this function is a memory hog if you have enough dice and sides), would I simply just yield each item in the list as it is being produced instead of throwing it into the result list?

EDIT: I came up with a way to break the list comprehension into loops after getting great responses and wanted to capture it:

```
def dice_rolls(dice, sides):
result = [[]]
for pool in [range(1, sides + 1)] * dice:
    temp_result = []
    for existing_values in result:  # existing_value same as x in list comp.
        for new_values in pool:  # new_value same as y in list comp.
            temp_result.append(existing_values + [new_values])
    result = temp_result
return result
```

Comment: If you have enough dice and sides for this function to be a memory problem, then even with a generator, you're going to have a time problem. You need to solve your underlying problem in a way that doesn't involve enumerating all throw results.

Comment: Um, just use `itertools.product` then?

Comment: Also, yeah, the docstring even mentions `itertools.product`.

Comment: I understand I could just use itertools.product, which is why I left it in the posted code, but I am trying to wrap my head around this specific list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct for this problem (and list comprehensions in general) would be to use recursion. Though YOU have asked for LOOPS, which is surprisingly challenging.

This is what I came up with;

```
def dice_rollsj(dice, sides):
    result = [[]]

    for num_dice in range(dice):
        temp_result = []
        for possible_new_values in range(1, sides+1):
            for existing_values in result:
                new_tuple = existing_values + [possible_new_values]
                temp_result.append(new_tuple)
        result = temp_result
```

I think that you'll get the same correct answers, but the numbers will be differently ordered. This may be due to the way the values are appended to the list. I don't know.... Let me know if this helps.

I tried to add as many lines as I could, because the goal was to expand and understand the comprehension.

Comment: Your answer works very well. I rewrote your code to use the original for loop, but your code it a little clearer as it splits `for pool in [range(1, sides + 1)] * dice:` Into two loops, but I wanted to see what it looked like with included. I see that you need the 2nd `temp_result` if you break it out into loops.

Comment: Yes I posted it at the top in the original post (under EDIT). Not sure how to post all the code in the sub-comments.

Answer (score 0):

you are redefining result with every iteration of the `for y in pool` loop. I believe what you want is to append the results:

```
result = []
for x in result:
   for y in pool:
      result.append(x + [y])
```

Comment: Except that you need to avoid stomping the `result` variable until *after* the loop.

Comment: I guess the part of the list comprehension that is confusing to me is: `for x in result`. For the first loop there is nothing in `result`, but an empty list, so it would add `[y]` to an empty list. But the end product no longer contains an empty list?

Comment: `[] + [y] -> [y]`

Comment: That does make more sense now, I would still like to rewrite this in a traditional FOR loop to aid in comprehension. Still plugging away.